# Own vector class input issue

Tags: c++, class

:) I am currently in the process of doing a practice exercise in writing classes, and I came across an issue when testing my code: the input does not appear to be working properly, since, regardless of what vector I input, the output always returns the (signed, if I multiply by a negative) zero vector. Any help would be highly appreciated! Thank you :) (Perhaps I am being obtuse, but I am not seeing where the problem is

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Vector {
private:
    double x, y, z; // Coordinates
    double scalar;

public:
    Vector(double x1, double y1, double z1) {
        x=x1; y=y1; z=z1;
    }

    Vector operator+ (Vector a) {
        x += a.x;
        y += a.y;
        z += a.z;
        return *this;
    }

    friend Vector operator* (Vector a, double scalar) {
        a.x *= scalar;
        a.y *= scalar;
        a.z *= scalar;
        return a;
    }

    friend Vector operator* (double scalar, Vector a) {
        a.x *= scalar;
        a.y *= scalar;
        a.z *= scalar;
        return a;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, Vector a) {
        o << "(" << a.x << ", " << a.y << ", " << a.z << ")";
        return o;
    }

    friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& i, Vector a) {
        char c;
        i >> c >> a.x >> c >> a.y >> c >> a.z >> c;
        return i;
    }

    double get(char i) const {
        if (i=='x') return x;
        if (i=='y') return y;
        if (i=='z') return z;
    }

};
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem in your `operator>>`. You should pass reference of `Vector` like so:

```
friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& i, Vector& a) 
//                                                      ^
```

Otherwise `a` is a local variable and it will not change.

And btw. Your `operator+` works as `+=`. It should create new `Vector`.

Comment: Thank you ever so much - that fixed it! I just could not see what was wrong with it for, like, two hours :) Tells me I need to go back and review references, since that is not the first time that I mess up on them.. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

I refactored your program to suit your need. There are a lot of scope for optimization though.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

class Vector
{
private:
    double x, y, z; // Coordinates

public:
    Vector() : x(0), y(0), z(0) {}
    Vector(double x1, double y1, double z1) : x(x1), y(y1), z(z1) {}

    Vector operator+ (Vector const & rhs) const {
        return Vector(this->x + rhs.x, this->y + rhs.y, this->z + rhs.z);
    }

    friend Vector operator* (Vector const & lhs, double s) {
        return Vector(lhs.x * s, lhs.y * s, lhs.z * s);
    }

    friend Vector operator* (double s, Vector const & rhs) {
        return Vector(rhs.x * s, rhs.y * s, rhs.z * s);
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream & os, Vector const & a) {
        os << "(" << a.x << ", " << a.y << ", " << a.z << ")";
        return os;
    }

    friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream & is, Vector & a) { // This needs to be a &, to be modified
        char c; // To dump extra characters
        is >> c >> a.x >> c >> a.y >> c >> a.z >> c;
        return is;
    }
    double get(char i) const {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 'x' : return x;
            case 'y' : return y;
            case 'z' : return z;
            default  : throw std::runtime_error("Vector doesn't contain specified character");
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Vector v1 = Vector(2.3, 3.5, 4.7); std::cout << v1 << std::endl;
    Vector v2 = Vector(1.4, 6.7, 1.1); std::cout << v2 << std::endl;
    Vector v3 = v1 + v2;               std::cout << v3 << std::endl;
    Vector v4 = 3 * v1;                std::cout << v4 << std::endl;
    Vector v5 = v2 * 5;                std::cout << v5 << std::endl;

    std::cout << v5.get('x') << std::endl;
    std::stringstream ss; ss << "(1,2,3)";
    Vector v6;                         std::cout << v6 << std::endl;
    ss >> v6;                          std::cout << v6 << std::endl;
    Vector v7 = 3 * v6;                std::cout << v7 << std::endl;
}
```

Output -

```
$ g++  vector.cpp -o vector && ./vector
(2.3, 3.5, 4.7)
(1.4, 6.7, 1.1)
(3.7, 10.2, 5.8)
(6.9, 10.5, 14.1)
(7, 33.5, 5.5)
7
(0, 0, 0)
(1, 2, 3)
(3, 6, 9)
```

Well, do go through it. If you need any more explanation, I would be happy to help.